# How to resolve - 'unable to read LDAP response packet: eoc child not allowed with definite length' error in Golang?

Tags: go, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to fetch employee attributes (firstname, lastname, emailID etc.) from active directory and facing error - unable to read LDAP response packet: eoc child not allowed with definite length.
Detailed error is mentioned below.
I am referring to - https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-ldap/ldap/v3#example-package-UserAuthentication

I have connected to the AD instance from Apache directory studio and confirm that attributes names mentioned in `entry.GetAttributeValue()` are correct.

Can you please help me to understand why I am facing this error

```golang
package ldap

import (
    "fmt"
    "log/slog"

    "example.com/myapp/internal/datamodel"
    "example.com/myapp/internal/logging"
    "github.com/go-ldap/ldap/v3"
)

const (
    BindUsername = "CN=s-someuser    (Company),OU=Accounts,OU=Users,DC=ad,DC=ent,DC=company,DC=com"
    BindPassword = "Password123"
    FQDN         = "ldap://hostname:389"
    BaseDN       = "DC=ad,DC=ent,DC=example,DC=com"
)

var logger = logging.GetLogger()

func bindAndSearchLDAPEntry(filter string) (*ldap.SearchResult, error) {
    ldapconn, err := ldap.DialURL(FQDN)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("Failed to connect to LDAP", slog.String("Error", err.Error()))
        return nil, err
    }
    defer ldapconn.Close()

    ldapconn.Start()
    err = ldapconn.Bind(BindUsername, BindPassword)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error(err.Error())
        return nil, err
    }

    searchReq := ldap.NewSearchRequest(BaseDN, ldap.ScopeWholeSubtree, ldap.NeverDerefAliases, 0, 0, false, filter, []string{}, nil)

    result, err := ldapconn.Search(searchReq)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("Error while searching LDAP", slog.String("Filter", filter), slog.String("Error", err.Error()))
        return nil, err
    }
    return result, nil
}

func GetEmployeeDetailsFromActiveDirectory() {
    emp := new(datamodel.Employee)
    result, err := bindAndSearchLDAPEntry("(sAMAccountName=UserName)")
    if err != nil && len(result.Entries) == 1 {
        entry := result.Entries[0]
        emp.GlobalEmployeeNumber = entry.GetAttributeValue("employeeID")
        emp.Username = entry.GetAttributeValue("sAMAccountName")
        emp.FirstName = entry.GetAttributeValue("givenName")
        emp.LastName = entry.GetAttributeValue("sn")
        fmt.Printf("%v", emp)
    } else if err != nil && len(result.Entries) == 0 {
        logger.Error("Did not find any entries in LDAP", slog.String("Error", err.Error()))
    } else if err != nil {
        logger.Error("Found multiple entries in LDAP", slog.String("Error", err.Error()))
    }
}
```

```golang
package datamodel

type Employee struct {
    FirstName            string `json:"firstname"`
    LastName             string `json:"lastname"`
    Username             string `json:"username"`
    EmailID              string `json:"emailid"`
    GlobalEmployeeNumber string `json:"globalemployeenumber"`
}
```

Error:

```bash
time=2023-10-10T08:55:28.808Z level=ERROR source=C:/code/tutorials/myapp/internal/ldap/activedirectory.go:41 msg="Error while searching LDAP" Filter="(sAMAccountName=UserName)" Error="unable to read LDAP response packet: eoc child not allowed with definite length"
panic: send on closed channel [recovered]
        panic: close of closed channel

goroutine 9 [running]:
github.com/go-ldap/ldap/v3.(*Conn).processMessages.func1()
        C:/Users/UserName/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-ldap/ldap/v3@v3.4.6/conn.go:499 +0x2e5
panic({0x62f840?, 0x70d4e0?})
        C:/apps/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:914 +0x21f
github.com/go-ldap/ldap/v3.(*Conn).processMessages(0xc000136480)
        C:/Users/UserName/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-ldap/ldap/v3@v3.4.6/conn.go:505 +0xf2
created by github.com/go-ldap/ldap/v3.(*Conn).Start in goroutine 1
        C:/Users/UserName/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-ldap/ldap/v3@v3.4.6/conn.go:268 +0x96
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x8 pc=0x5586e9]

goroutine 1 [running]:
example.com/myapp/internal/ldap.GetEmployeeDetailsFromActiveDirectory()
        C:/code/tutorials/myapp/internal/ldap/activedirectory.go:50 +0x49
main.main()
        C:/code/tutorials/myapp/cmd/apiserver/myapv.go:25 +0xf
exit status 2
```

Comment: After going through it multiple times looks like ```ldapconn.Start()``` is the culprit. After commenting it out, employee details were fetched from Active Directory. Will keep this question open to understand what is the role of ```ldapconn.Start()``` from someone.